# wordpress files could not downloaded on Mozilla

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I run wordpress+woocommerce, but when user try to download file from the site,

Mozilla show that:

secure connection failed

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified. Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Only work in Chrome.

And when I upgrade wordpress to v5.4 woocommerce v4, it has this issue!

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: Check your TLS version and SSL cert. Firefox/Mozilla I believe, now requires TLS 1.2 or higher. https://hacks.mozilla.org/2020/02/its-the-boot-for-tls-1-0-and-tls-1-1/ You can test your SSL cert here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question, but rather a server SSL/TLS question.

Comment: Thank you, I check it and also changed the SSL, but nothing happened. I also check ssllabs, it give A grade.